# Android website doesn't show up in webview

Tags: android, android-webview

I am trying to show maps.google.com website thru WebView in Android emulator but I am not seeing the web site and seeing only Loading.

I am able to see other sites like www.google.com.  Do I need to enable more settings for sites like maps.google.com?

Permission in the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Code

```
            WebView view= (WebView) findViewById(R.id.view1);
            View.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            View.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true); 
            View.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
            View.loadUrl("http://maps.google.com");
```

Comment: is there any error shown in logcat?

Comment: Please Print some logcate here that shows the error..

Comment: @nik : "I am able to see other sites like www.google.com." please read this line. and also, he doesn't get any error..

Comment: @Bret Lee - what is your android sdk version for this application? is Android API or Google API ?

Comment: Sorry, I was not able to see it in the emulator not in the device (updated my post). Versions: OS Windows emulator-5554, Eclipse 3.7.0, Android Sdk version 13. I don't see any errors in the Eclipse console log.

Answer (score 0):

please try to run simulator with google api instead of normal simulator, i am sure you got it.

it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use MapView instead of a WebView.  It gives you much better control over the map.
You'll need to get an apiKey from google, associated with the keystore you're using (it only takes a minute to do that), but it's worth the trouble.  Just remember that if you're running it straight out of eclipse (rather than as an installed .apk) you'll also need to get an apiKey associated with your eclipse debug keystore.